# Using a datetime object for a simple regression

Tags: python

I imported some data from Yahoo Finance and saved it to a csv. Then I parsed the data into two arrays: time and price. I converted the price into float and the dates into datetime objects. However, when I try to use that data to run a regression, I get this error:

"TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"

How can I get the summary to work? Any advice is appreciated. My code is below

```
def data_to_array(ticker):
   dates = []
   prices = []

   data = csv.reader(open('path', 'r+'), delimiter = ",", quotechar = '|')

   for row in data:
       dates.append(row[0])
       prices.append(row[1])


   for i in range(0, len(prices)):
       prices[i] = float(prices[i])

   for j in range(len(dates)):
       dates[j] = datetime.strptime(dates[j], '%Y-%m-%d')

   return(dates, prices)
```

and here is my regression function:

```
def simple_regression(dates, prices):

    y = prices
    x1 = dates

    print(x1)

    x = sm.add_constant(x1)
    results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
    results.summary()
```

Comment: If you're working with time series data, then OLS might not be what you want (unless you're trying to predict the price based on a single number, like hour of the day or seconds since unix epoch) Statsmodels has some [examples of time-series prediction](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/index.html#stats) in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem

The problem is that for regression to work you need numerical data for both axis. To covert a date time into a numerical format we can convert them into UTC time stamps.

> Solution

In Python you can use this function to get the UTC format of a datetime object:

```
timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
```

Where timestamp is the UTC timestamp and dt is the date time object.

So incorporating it into your code:

Change the line

```
x1 = dates
```

And replace it with

```
x1 = [dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() for dt in dates]
```

NOTE: Since a UTC timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970, your slope will be in seconds. If you are graphing, the x axis will be in seconds.

To convert a set of UTC timestamps back into datetime objects:

```
   datetimes = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp) for timestamp in timestamps]
```

Where timestamps are the UTC timestamps and datetimes are the equivalent time stamp objects.

Comment: Thanks so much. So I was able to process the results.summary. So now I have an equation for a regression line, how do I convert the UTC values into datetime so that my graph doesn't have seconds as the x axis?